# Add a navigation item to a view controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I had a Navigation Controller based application and decided to use tab bars. And in some views I don't need to have a navigation controller assigned to a view controller but I still want to have an "add" button at the right top corner of my view.

What is the easiest view to accomplish this? I tried to add a navigation item to my view but it doesn't seem to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do is to make the view a `UINavigationViewController` so that you can access the `navigationItem`, even if you don't push a view onto the stack.

I'm not sure of a way to just have a `UINavigationBar` and assign the button.

Or you could try and mess around with a `UIToolbar` and see if you can tweak it to your satisfaction